# Change div property in JavaScript for indexed value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the left padding value of the div class `switch-selection` in JavaScript. The following from my JavaScript function changes all values.

```
var ind = 1; //getting index from php variable '1' is just an example

$(".switch-selection").css("paddingLeft","60px");
```

I need to change only the value of the current `index` value.  I have tried:

```
$(".switch-selection")[ind].css("paddingLeft","60px");
```

But that gives me an error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **[`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** selector or **[`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** method to specify the index of element :

```
$(".switch-selection:eq("+ind+")").css("paddingLeft","60px");
//OR
$(".switch-selection").eq(ind).css("paddingLeft","60px");
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var ind=2;

$(".switch-selection:eq("+ind+")").css("paddingLeft","60px");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="switch-selection">DIV 1</div>
<div class="switch-selection">DIV 2</div>
<div class="switch-selection">DIV 3</div>
<div class="switch-selection">DIV 4</div>
<div class="switch-selection">DIV 5</div>
```

Comment: Is that what you're looking for @ian?

Answer (score 1):

Use `eq()` to keep it as a jQuery object, since `css()` is a jQuery method.

```
$(".switch-selection").eq(ind).css("paddingLeft","60px");
```

Answer (score 1):

The other responses addressed the index portion of your question.  However, the CSS property for padding on an element's left is `padding-left`, not `paddingLeft`.  `paddingLeft` is the *Javascript* property name.